# How to change this date format of this '13/11/2017'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Show the code that is generating the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it normally will be yyyy-mm-dd so you might require to provide explicit type as below:

```
Select convert(date, '13/11/2017',103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You souhld check the *style* parameter.

```
convert(data_type, expression, stlye)
```

In your case:

```
convert(date, '13/11/2017',103)
```

Most popular date conversions:

```
convert(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy', 103)

convert(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy', 101)

convert(date, 'dd-mm-yyyy', 105)
```

See more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql